# List.AddRange Has Some Invalid Arguments

Tags: list, generics, interface

I want to create a list of flowers (for example) that conform to a predefined `IFlower` interface as below.

```
public interface IFlower
{
    string colour { get; }
    int petals { get; }
}

public class Rose : IFlower
{
    public Rose()
    {
        string[] colours = new string[]{ "Pink", "Orange", "Red", "Crimson", "Cerise" };
        Random random = new Random();
        colour = colours[random.Next(0, 4)];
    }

    public string colour { get; set; }

    public int petals
    {
        get { return 8; }
    }
}

public class Daisy : IFlower{
    public Daisy()
    {
        string[] colours = new string[]{ "White", "Yellow", "Purple" };
        Random random = new Random();
        colour = colours[random.Next(0, 2)];
    }

    public string colour { get; set; }

    public int  petals
    {
        get { return 18; }
    }
}

public class Flowers
{
    public List<Daisy> Daisies
    {
        get
        {
            List<Daisy> items = new List<Daisy>();
            items.Add(new Daisy());
            items.Add(new Daisy());
            return items;
        }
    }

    public List<Rose> Roses
    {
        get
        {
            List<Rose> items = new List<Rose>();
            items.Add(new Rose());
            items.Add(new Rose());
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I run the following code to create the concatenated list:

```
    public List<IFlower> Flowers
    {
        get
        {
            List<IFlower> output = new List<IFlower>();
            output.AddRange(Daisies);
            output.AddRange(Roses);
            return output;
        }
    }
```

I get the error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IFlower>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IFlower>)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: I don't see where you created the Daisies and Roses collections, so we can't see what type they have.  The compiler error usually means that the function argument has the wrong type.  Can you add the code that defines the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Roses and Daisies tokens must each refer to an instance of a class implementing

```
IEnumerable<IFlower>
```

So I guess that one or both of them refers to something else.

Comment: Okay, my mistake was making `IEnumerable<Daisy>` and `IEnumerable<Rose>` and expecting them to be concatenated into `List<IFlower>` :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Aha, perhaps it would work if you cast them explicitly (this assumes that IEnumerable<'T> is contravariant, which as of this writing means it must be C# 4.0, and not silverlight).  In other words, I would expect this to work: `List<IFlower> output = new List<IFlower>(); output.AddRange((IEnumerable<IFlower>)Daisies); output.AddRange((IEnumerable<IFlower>)Roses); return output;`